# Sliding drawer - how to make it pull from above?

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I'm making a game for 2 players, this is a mockup, the problem is with the sliding drawer on top - purple one. The "handle" button must be exactly the opposite to blue handle below. How do I reverse it?
[image]

Comment: do you mean to make the text look upside down or what exactly? Because in that case, just add android:rotation = "180" to the button.

Comment: @Filnik, i want it to be upside down, the text and the drawer must pull from above to down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the top purple drawer is a `RelativeLayout`, just set in the button the [`ALIGN_PARENT_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_TOP) to `true`. If the drawer is not a `RelativeLayout`, declare one `RelativeLayout`(which fills all the purple drawer) inside it and put in it the button with [`ALIGN_PARENT_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_TOP) to `true`.

Then, for having the text in the button upside down, just add `android:rotation="180"` to the button in your XML file or give the button a 180 degree rotation programatically.